# Load Rss feeds from a PHP file on a remote server into a div in a phonegap app?

Tags: php, html, cordova, rss

How can I load my rss feeds from a PHP file from remote server (currently my localhost) into a div in my phonegap app?

I have tested the PHP file, the rss feeds are displaying ok when on the browser, but when i try to load the file into the div in my phonegap app, i get nothing. my code is below

```
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
    <!-- WARNING: for iOS 7, remove the width=device-width and height=device-height attributes. See https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-4323 -->
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width, height=device-height, target-densitydpi=device-dpi" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
    <title>RSS APP</title>
</head>
<body>


<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.ajaxtrigger').click(function(){
$('#rsshere').load('http://localhost:88/example-rss.php');
 });
});
 </script>
    <div class="app2">

        <div id="rsshere">LOAD RSS CONTENT HERE</div>      
 </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
</body>
```

PHP CODE FOR 'example-rss.php' on my local host, which correctly desplays the feeds in a browser

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

if (!ini_get('date.timezone')) {
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Prague');
}

require_once '/Feed.php';

$rss = Feed::loadRss('http://www.herald.co.zw/feed/');

 ?>

 <h1><?php echo htmlSpecialChars($rss->title) ?></h1>

 <p><i><?php echo htmlSpecialChars($rss->description) ?></i></p>

 <?php foreach ($rss->item as $item): ?>
 <h2><a href="<?php echo htmlSpecialChars($item->link) ?>">
 <?php echo        htmlSpecialChars($item->title) ?></a>
<small><?php echo date("j.n.Y H:i", (int) $item->timestamp) ?></small></h2>

<?php if (isset($item->{'content:encoded'})): ?>
    <div><?php echo $item->{'content:encoded'} ?></div>
<?php else: ?>
    <p><?php echo htmlSpecialChars($item->description) ?></p>
<?php endif ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
```

FINALLY, THE PHP FOR 'Feed.php' called on line 8 (not sure if its needed but included the code anyway)

```
/** @var string */
public static $cacheDir;

/** @var SimpleXMLElement */
protected $xml;


/**
 * Loads RSS channel.
 * @param  string  RSS feed URL
 * @param  string  optional user name
 * @param  string  optional password
 * @return Feed
 * @throws FeedException
 */
public static function loadRss($url, $user = NULL, $pass = NULL)
{
     $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(self::httpRequest($url, $user, $pass),
  LIBXML_NOWARNING | LIBXML_NOERROR);
    if (!$xml->channel) {
        throw new FeedException('Invalid channel.');
    }

    self::adjustNamespaces($xml->channel);

    foreach ($xml->channel->item as $item) {
        // converts namespaces to dotted tags
        self::adjustNamespaces($item);

        // generate 'timestamp' tag
        if (isset($item->{'dc:date'})) {
            $item->timestamp = strtotime($item->{'dc:date'});
        } elseif (isset($item->pubDate)) {
            $item->timestamp = strtotime($item->pubDate);
        }
    }

    $feed = new self;
    $feed->xml = $xml->channel;
    return $feed;
}


/**
 * Loads Atom channel.
 * @param  string  Atom feed URL
 * @param  string  optional user name
 * @param  string  optional password
 * @return Feed
 * @throws FeedException
 */
public static function loadAtom($url, $user = NULL, $pass = NULL)
{
    $xml = new SimpleXMLElement(self::httpRequest($url, $user, $pass),
LIBXML_NOWARNING | LIBXML_NOERROR);
    if (!in_array('http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom', $xml->getDocNamespaces(), 
TRUE)) {
        throw new FeedException('Invalid channel.');
    }

    // generate 'timestamp' tag
    foreach ($xml->entry as $entry) {
        $entry->timestamp = strtotime($entry->updated);
    }

    $feed = new self;
    $feed->xml = $xml;
    return $feed;
}


/**
 * Returns property value. Do not call directly.
 * @param  string  tag name
 * @return SimpleXMLElement
 */
public function __get($name)
{
    return $this->xml->{$name};
}


/**
 * Sets value of a property. Do not call directly.
 * @param  string  property name
 * @param  mixed   property value
 * @return void
 */
public function __set($name, $value)
{
    throw new Exception("Cannot assign to a read-only property '$name'.");
}


/**
 * Converts a SimpleXMLElement into an array.
 * @param  SimpleXMLElement
 * @return array
 */
public function toArray(SimpleXMLElement $xml = NULL)
{
    if ($xml === NULL) {
        $xml = $this->xml;
    }

    if (!$xml->children()) {
        return (string) $xml;
    }

    $arr = array();
    foreach ($xml->children() as $tag => $child) {
        if (count($xml->$tag) === 1) {
            $arr[$tag] = $this->toArray($child);
        } else {
            $arr[$tag][] = $this->toArray($child);
        }
    }

    return $arr;
}


/**
 * Process HTTP request.
 * @param  string  URL
 * @param  string  user name
 * @param  string  password
 * @return string
 * @throws FeedException
 */
private static function httpRequest($url, $user, $pass)
{
    if (self::$cacheDir) {
        $cacheFile = self::$cacheDir . '/feed.' . md5($url) . '.xml';
        if (@filemtime($cacheFile) + self::$cacheExpire > time()) {
            return file_get_contents($cacheFile);
        }
    }

    if (extension_loaded('curl')) {
        $curl = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        if ($user !== NULL || $pass !== NULL) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$user:$pass");
        }
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 20);
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE); // no echo, just
 return result
        if (!ini_get('open_basedir')) {
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE); // sometime is
useful :)
        }
        $result = trim(curl_exec($curl));
        $ok = curl_errno($curl) === 0 && curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) === 200;

    } elseif ($user === NULL && $pass === NULL) {
        $result = trim(file_get_contents($url));
        $ok = is_string($result);

    } else {
        throw new FeedException('PHP extension CURL is not loaded.');
    }

    if (!$ok) {
        if (isset($cacheFile)) {
            $result = @file_get_contents($cacheFile);
            if (is_string($result)) {
                return $result;
            }
        }
        throw new FeedException('Cannot load channel.');
    }

    if (isset($cacheFile)) {
        file_put_contents($cacheFile, $result);
    }

    return $result;
}


/**
 * Generates better accessible namespaced tags.
 * @param  SimpleXMLElement
 * @return void
 */
private static function adjustNamespaces($el)
{
    foreach ($el->getNamespaces(TRUE) as $prefix => $ns) {
        $children = $el->children($ns);
        foreach ($children as $tag => $content) {
            $el->{$prefix . ':' . $tag} = $content;
        }
    }
}

}



/**
 * An exception generated by Feed.
 */
class FeedException extends Exception
{
}
```

EDIT TO INCLUDE CONFIG.XML

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <access uri="http://192.168.1.35" subdomains="true" />
<widget id="io.cordova.hellocordova" version="0.0.1"
 xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" 
 xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0">
<name>HelloCordova</name>
<description>
    A sample Apache Cordova application that responds to the deviceready
 event.
</description>
<author email="dev@cordova.apache.org" href="http://cordova.io">
    Apache Cordova Team
</author>
<content src="index.html" />
<access origin="*" />
</widget>
```

Comment: where do you test the app? emulator? device?

Comment: i have been testing it on an emulator, but i also have a device to test on @jcesarmobile

Comment: and it isn't working on any of them? on the device it isn't going to work because you are using localhost, but it should work on emulator. Anyway, use the local IP of the machine with the server instead of localhost, and whitelist the IP too on the config.xml

Comment: i white-listed my IP in the config.xml, i have updated the post to reflect the code, its right at the bottom take a look, i still cannot get it to work. i also changed the .load from localhost to the ip address, still isn't working  @jcesarmobile